# How to set up a persistent memory block device on a Docker container?

Tags: docker, persistent-memory

I want to use a tool for testing persistent memory programs (). Due to dependencies, this tool needs to be setup in an old version of linux. So I have to use either a virtual machine or a docker container.

I currently have a docker container with ubuntu 14.04. I'm trying to setup the tool as mentioned in the repo's README.

"To permanantly allocate space for persistent memory in a Ubuntu system, first we need to add a kernel boot parameter.

Edit `/etc/default/grub` with sudo privilege. Change line:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`"

However, a docker container does not have a grub file, so I'm not sure how I should do this.

I'm fairly new to docker. Is this something that is possible, or should I settle for a virtual machine?

Comment: This is not something that docker will have access to, since you are changing the physical layer memory mappings. Your going to need to set it up in the host. If it needs an old version of linux, check the kernel version. If it requires an old kernel, a VM is the only way. If its compatible with newer kernels, you could do all the kernel config outside the docker container, and just run the userspace and tool inside the docker container.

Comment: `kernel boot parameter` Kernel is shared between OS and docker containers.